# check if username doesnt contain numbers or other weird signs? PHP

Tags: php

i have a username but i want to check if the username doenst contain any numbers or other things that does not belong in a username.

Example:

```
if ($username !contain "1234567890/.,;'\[]") {
send username to db
} else {
echo 'your username is incorrect';
}
```

How do i do this?
the username is represents the real name in my code.

Comment: What did your research come up with?

Comment: What puzzles me is why do you think numbers or dots don't belong in a username.

Comment: @apokryfos the username sould represent your real name in this case so no numbers or anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the 1000 ways you can do this, one is regular expressions:

```
if (!preg_match("![0-9/.,;'\\\[\]]!", $username))  {
    //send username to db
} else {
   echo 'your username is incorrect';
}
```

An alternative is to whitelist permitted characters rather than blacklist invalid ones:

```
//Allows letters and a single quote (not uncommon in some names)
if (preg_match("!^[A-Za-z']+$!", $username))  { 
    //send username to db
} else {
   echo 'your username is incorrect';
}
```

Comment: don't forget, though: the better option would be a whitelist, your regex would allow, for example, `^`

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thanks! @FranzGleichmann thanks i will be looking into it!

Answer (score 2):

Try `preg_match`

Searches username for a match to the regular expression given in pattern.